# Tweepy stream.filter() connection keeps timing out but stream.sample() works just fine

Tags: python, tweepy

So I'm trying to stream some data using Tweepy version 4.3.0. I've also tried with 4.2.0 and < 4.0.0 and the same message is returned after about 90 sec:

> "Stream connection has errored or timed out"

The connection is not terminated after the message is returned.

My code is:

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(credentials.API_KEY, credentials.API_SECRET_KEY)
auth.set_access_token(credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN, credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

print(api.verify_credentials().screen_name)

class IDPrinter(tweepy.Stream):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.id)

printer = IDPrinter(credentials.API_KEY,
                    credentials.API_SECRET_KEY,
                    credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN,
                    credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

printer.filter(track=["Tesla"])
```

Just like in the official [Tweepy documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v4.3.0/streaming.html).

However, if instead of:

```
printer.filter(track=["Tesla"])
```

I use:

```
printer.sample()
```

Then data is being streamed as expected.
I have also tried a bunch of keywords, including "I", "the", " ", etc. and none of them yield any results.

Also, the fact that the sample() method works fine tells me that my credentials are valid. I've read over the documentation a few times already, so any help will be much appreciated!

EDIT: I have also tried low volume track keywords and I still encounter the issue.

EDIT2: This was a connection issue caused by the corporate firewall at my workplace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Tweepy logs this when a connection error is encountered.
You can override this using [`Stream.on_connection_error`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.3.0/stream.html#tweepy.Stream.on_connection_error).

The connection doesn't terminate because Tweepy automatically handles the connection error and attempts to reconnect.

There are many possible reasons for the stream getting disconnected.
See the Disconnections section of the [Twitter API documentation on connecting to a streaming endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/connecting).
Since those keywords would be very high volume, it's possible that you're falling too far behind on the stream.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!
Do you have any suggestions to fix or better troubleshoot my issue?
Thanks!

Comment: If you don't encounter the issue with lower volume keywords then it's likely that the volume for the other keywords you're trying is too high for your system to handle.

Comment: I am actually encountering issues with any use case of the filter() method.
The only case where I don't encounter issues is with the sample() method, which should be, in theory, much higher volume.

Comment: Tweepy is handling one of these exceptions: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/ecd1ef73cc1186299f2401cf83b6f804211ee846/tweepy/streaming.py#L157-L160. You could try re-raising it before the `on_connection_error` call, but most of these are indicative of a connection issue that shouldn't be exclusive to `filter`.

Comment: It might be because I'm trying to stream from within a corporate firewall, so I will try again from my computer when I can. Although I still don't understand why sample() works just find under the same conditions, filter() and sample() are only different in the sense that filter() only streams if the conditions specified are true, right?

Comment: The only relevant difference is that `filter` is a `POST` request while `sample` is a `GET` request.

Comment: That may very well be the issue. Will update later on whether this is a firewall related issue or not.

Comment: Update: this was, indeed, a connection issues caused by the corporate firewall. Works fine from home PC